# Can someone [explain] this to me?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain) is supposed to be "a SQL command that shows the execution plan of a query", but sometimes it's used for questions where they are asking explanations about something, like [a piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423214/heap-sort-explanation-needed-here). I think we should disambiguate this by closing the obvious bad questions and retagging everything else as [explain-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain-plan) (or any other name, since  MySQL seems to call it "show plan").

There are ~200 questions tagged. Some might need closure. Use your best judgment.

Answer (score 9):

[explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain) talks a lot about the explain plan of SQL queries (and those that don't should be edited).

[explain-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain-plan) talks *directly* about explain plans.  However, it *feels* like it should be a synonym of...

...[query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization)...but perhaps those two can stand on their own.

So for this particular case I'm torn.  We don't want the [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain) tag to lurk around for too long, but retagging to [explain-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain-plan) doesn't make sense if they're looking for query optimization help.

I suggest that [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain) and [explain-plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain-plan) be made synonyms of [query-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization) instead.  If anyone does want to delve into this and figure out what should stick around and what shouldn't, it'd be great if other outstanding issues with the questions could be fixed too.

Comment: I doubt that anyone  looking for "query optimization" would use "explain plan" unless they want some kind of counsel while showing the results of the explain plan.

Comment: Less than 50 questions left after filtering out most database-related ones. Those should mostly need correction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explain+-mysql+-mongodb+-sql+-db2+-sqlite+-postgresql+-explain-plan?sort=active&pageSize=50

Comment: I went through that query and cleaned out all the questions that were using "explain" as a meta tag ("please explain this to me...").  It looks like elasticsearch also has an explain?

Comment: In Oracle, `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN PLAN` are the same statement. In sqlite3, `EXPLAIN` gives you bytecodes, `EXPLAIN PLAN` doesn't exist, `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` gives you the declarative plan. In MySQL, `EXPLAIN` is a synonym for `DESCRIBE`, which gives you information about tables, queries, or anything else. And so on. So, specifically looking for `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN PLAN` or whatever instead of `query-optimization` doesn't make sense unless you're talking about a DBMS-specific statement.

Comment: @Makoto "explain plan" is clearly a subset of query optimisation - I don't think it makes sense to make them synonyms...

Comment: @JasonMArcher did you voted to close also?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, for the ones that warranted.  I had to wait for my votes to refresh to get the last few.